# How to use unset() for this Linear Linked List in PHP

Tags: php, reference, unset

I'm writing a simple linear linked list implementation in PHP. This is basically just for practice... part of a [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problem. I'm not sure if I should be using [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to help in garbage collection in order to avoid memory leaks. Should I include an unset() for head and temp in the destructor of LLL?

I understand that I'll use unset() to delete nodes when I want, but is unset() necessary for general clean up at any point?

Is the memory map freed once the script terminates even if you don't use unset()?

[I saw this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251113/should-i-use-unset-in-php-destruct), but I'm still a little unclear. Is the answer that you simply don't have to use unset() to avoid any sort of memory leaks associated with creating references?

I'm using PHP 5.. btw.

[Unsetting references in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php)

[PHP references tutorial](http://safalra.com/programming/php/references-tutorial/)

Here is the code - I'm creating references when I create $temp and $this->head at certain points in the LLL class:

```
class Node
{
    public $data;
    public $next;
}
class LLL
{
    // The first node
    private $head;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->head = NULL;
    }
    public function insertFirst($data)
    {
        if (!$this->head)
        {
            // Create the head
            $this->head = new Node;
            $temp =& $this->head;
            $temp->data = $data;
            $temp->next = NULL;                     
        } else
        {
            // Add a node, and make it the new head.
            $temp = new Node;        
            $temp->next = $this->head;
            $temp->data = $data;
            $this->head =& $temp;
        }
    }
    public function showAll()
    {
        echo "The linear linked list:<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        if ($this->head)
        {               
            $temp =& $this->head;
            do
            {
                echo $temp->data . " ";
            } while ($temp =& $temp->next);
        } else
        {
            echo "is empty.";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the memory map freed once the script
>   terminates even if you don't use
>   unset()?

Yes - when a script ends, *all* of the memory resources allocated by it are freed.