# is it a good idea to unset($this) in class destructor

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use unset in php __destruct()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251113/should-i-use-unset-in-php-destruct)

Is it a good idea to unset($this) in class destruct and what difference it will make ?

```
function __destruct(){
  unset($this);

 }
```

Comment: Even if this can make a memory issue, you *already* have created a design issue that will prevent you from dealing properly with it. Your question is highly theoretic I must admit. Instead respect your senses and take it as a smell for a design problem with connecting everything to `$this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$this` is a special variable in PHP](http://php.net/this) - that special, it's pseudo. I wonder if you could unset it at all from within a class/object context, maybe in earlier PHP versions, but then you should consider it a flaw.

Do not do that. Unset the object pointer (that is from the outside), and garbage collection takes care on it's own.

The `__destruct` function is for unsetting such "outer" object pointers that are actually internal to the `$this` object, like if you use aggregation and composition.

Especially with circular references, it might help the PHP garbage collector to do the job more efficiently. But this does not depend on `$this` but what the object actually carries which means it highly depend on concrete code.

Are you running into an actual memory issue you have the feeling the garbage collector can not deal with? Only if you can answer that with *Yes*, you normally need to think about `__destruct`.

Comment: If there is only a single instance of what is represented by `$this`, there is no need to unset anything here. Even if you do `$this->template = $this`, PHP garbage collection will clear it up for you. I assume your question is more about being curious than running into a concrete issue, right?

Comment: prof, no, it won't create issues. PHP is garbage collected and any memory used will be freed when you drop all references to it (i.e., when nothing can reach the object anymore because it isn't in any variable).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is entirely pointless. `unset` does not free memory per se, it just marks it as a candidate for garbage collection, which is exactly what destroying an object already means.